# Javascript and visual studio: intellisense doesn't see javascript functions of content loaded asynchrnously

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating a web application using visual studio 2015 and ASP.NET MVC.

Some contents in the site are loaded asynchronously.

The situation is the following.

You have a view called _Layout.cshtml which is the basic HTML and style for the site. In this file there is an inclusion of Framework.js, which is a file containing some useful javascript functions that can be used everywhere in the site.

You have an other view, called Products.cshtml, which is rendered inside _Layout.cshtml.

In Product.cshtml you have a tab menu. Depending on the selected tab, a certain partial view is asynchronously loaded. 
Each partial view includes some javascript code specific to it's functionalities.

So, what is the problem?
While I'm coding javascript inside partial views loaded asynchronously, intellisense is not able to see functions of Framework.js, which is quite logic since myPartialView.js still doesn't know that it will be placed inside a view which references Framework.js.

Now my question is: is there any way to tell to the intellisense that Framework.js will be available, so that I can use the intellisense functionalities while I'm calling functions of Framework.js inside myPartialView.js?

Comment: did you create an empty application ?

Comment: No, MVC application with a basic template